# rsync with different ssh ports

Tags: ssh, rsync

This syntax works for one remote source/destination:

```
rsync -avz -e "ssh -p $portNumber" user@remoteip:/path/to/files/ /local/path/
```

Which syntax should I use if both source and destination have different SSH ports?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If both of them have different ports, it is a good time to start thinking about using a configuration files, such as `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host server1
  Port port1
Host server2
  Port port2
```

and you are all set up.